# PHP array not iterating through first part of chunk

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, stripe-payments

I have a PHP array called `$dataset` which has been split into two chunks. I am trying to create two Stripe subscription schedules based on each chunk.

The code below creates two schedules but only for the second part of the chunk `schedule_batch[1]` which is created twice. The first 9 items in the first chunk are not created at all.

The first chunk is completely ignored and the second chunk is processed twice.

I have removed the full contents of my array to keep the code example below simple, but it is in the format below and there are 20 items in the array.

```
    $dataset = array(
      array(
        "product" => $product->id,
        "unit_amount" => "2020",
        "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-12")) // Payment 1 Date
    
      ),
      array(
          "product" => $product->id,
          "unit_amount" => "2000",
          "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-15")) //Payment 2 Date
      ),
      array(
          "product" => $product->id,
          "unit_amount" => "3400",
          "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-16")) //Payment 3 Date
      ),
      array(
          "product" => $product->id,
          "unit_amount" => "3700",
          "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-18")) //Payment 4 Date
      ),
    );
    
    $schedule_batch = array_chunk($dataset, 9);
    $numberofbatches = count($schedule_batch);
    
    $phases = [];
    foreach ($schedule_batch as $index => $data) {
        $phases[] = [
          'end_date' => $data[$index]["end_date"],
          'transfer_data' => [
            'amount_percent' => $fee_percentage,
            'destination' => $account],        
          'proration_behavior' => 'none',
          'plans' => [
              [
                'price_data' => [
                  'unit_amount' => $data[$index]["unit_amount"],
                  'currency' => 'usd',
                  'product' => $data[$index]["product"],
                  'recurring' => [
                      'interval' => 'month',
                  ],
                ],
                
              ],
            ],
        ];
      }
    

function createSchedule ($customer, $phases) {
  $schedule = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
      'customer' => $customer,
      'expand' => ['subscription'],
      'start_date' => date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-10")),
      'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
      'phases' => $phases,
    ]);
  }
    
    foreach ($schedule_batch as $index => $data) {
      createSchedule($customer->id, $phases);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What is supposed to be in `$phases`?

Comment: $phases is just creating the price on Stripe and then changing price for the next iteration

Comment: I just realised I haven't added the function call to the code

Comment: It seems it might be simpler to run the `$phases` code over `$dataset` and then chunk `$phases` instead?

Comment: Would really appreciate a quick example :-)

Comment: Just change the `foreach ($schedule_batch as $index => $data) {` to `foreach ($dataset as $data)`, `$data[$index]` to `$data` inside the loop, and then add `$schedule_batch = array_chunk($phases, 9);` after the loop

Comment: For example https://3v4l.org/FrVlQ

Comment: Thanks, but its not letting me chunk $phases.  "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Comment: It works fine in my demo...

Comment: I can get the print_r to run fine. But its when I call my function, I get a message "You must provide a value for 'phases'

Comment: This is what I am running: foreach ($schedule_batch as $index => $data) {
createSchedule($customer->id, $phases);
}

Comment: That should probably be `foreach ($phases as $phase) createSchedule($customer->id, $phase); }` although without seeing all your code it's hard to be certain

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `foreach ($schedule_batch as $phase) {`

Comment: You are awesome @Nick! Think its working, just double checking

Comment: Cool. If it is, let me know and I'll post an answer

Comment: Hi @Nick, you were right and all working great now. If  you post the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: That's great to hear - I'm glad we got it working. I've posted an answer with the main points from the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to apply the code which generates `$phases` to `$dataset` and then chunk it into `$schedule_batch`:

```
$phases = [];
foreach ($dataset as $data) {
    $phases[] = [
      'end_date' => $data["end_date"],
      'transfer_data' => [
        'amount_percent' => 20,
        'destination' => 10],        
      'proration_behavior' => 'none',
      'plans' => [
          [
            'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => $data["unit_amount"],
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product' => $data["product"],
              'recurring' => [
                  'interval' => 'month',
              ],
            ],
            
          ],
        ],
    ];
  }

$schedule_batch = array_chunk($phases, 2);
$numberofbatches = count($schedule_batch);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FrVlQ)

Your final code to call `createSchedule` would then be:

```
foreach ($schedule_batch as $phase) {
    createSchedule($customer->id, $phase);
}
```